# Is there an elegant way to make a generic tuple struct with an unused type without PhantomData?

Tags: struct, tuples, rust, traits

I'd like to create a generic tuple struct `Producer` which can hold any type `P` which implements the trait `Produce<T>`, defined below. This produces the (expected) commented error:

```
trait Produce<T> {
    fn get(&mut self) -> T;
}

// ERROR: parameter `T` is never used [E0392]
struct Producer<P,T>(P) where P: Produce<T>;
```

If this were a non-tuple struct, I could remedy this issue by adding a `PhantomData<T>` field and writing a constructor `Producer::new(p: P)` to hide this as an implementation detail. However, I'm using this type as one of a family of tuple structs in a Builder API, so using a conventional struct + constructor feels pretty out of place.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In many cases, you don't want to parameterize your trait, but instead want an *associated type*:

```
trait Produce {
    type T;

    fn get(&mut self) -> Self::T;
}

struct Producer<P>(P) where P: Produce;

fn main() {}
```

Unfortunately, it's tough to tell if this will work for you without knowing a lot more about the anticipated use case and code examples, which might be too verbose for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'm using it to change a setting in the builder API of an object pool library. I've updated the documentation for [the tuple struct](http://zslayton.github.io/lifeguard/lifeguard/settings/struct.Supplier.html) and its [updated usage](http://zslayton.github.io/lifeguard/lifeguard/fn.pool.html). Thanks!